# Estimativa de tempo de execução - Select

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou realizando alguns testes de performance no meu BD utilizando o MySQL, e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida.

Existe alguma forma de prever quanto tempo irá demorar a execução de uma query no MySQL após o inicio da execução dela?

Verifiquei que em **Client Connections** consigo obter o estado da query, mas não quanto tempo irá levar (previsto).

Comment: isso? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profiles.html

Comment: Acredito que estimar o _tempo_ não seja possível. A execução em si depende de outros fatores que podem mudar após o início da execução, como por exemplo, a disponibilidade de recursos, a capacidade de processamento e taxa de I/O do próprio servidor onde o serviço de banco está sendo executado... um pá de coisa. Acho que não há uma maneira cabal de se determinar esse tempo. Particularmente,acho justo. Melhor não ter uma informação do que ter uma informação errada ou inconsistente.

Comment: O problema com o Show profiles Wees é que ele só mostra a duração da query, e não uma previsão de duração o talt de duração só é apresentado após a conclusão

Comment: Sim. Ele faz, e **depois** de fazer ele diz quanto tempo levou para fazer.

Comment: Concordo com sua opinião Diego, o problema e que ele não mostra nem uma estimativa básica sabe, por exemplo: Tenho de trazer mil linhas e já carreguei 500, tendo isso poderíamos ter alguma noção do tempo, mesmo ela não sendo precisa já seria um norte

Comment: Mesmo isso é complicado. Porque ele não vai varrendo **todos** os registros da tabela e vai pegando de um a um. Ele elabora um plano para selecionar os registros e a ação de ir buscá-los é uma tacada só (talvez mais que uma em caso de paginação e/ou particionamento). Ele não sabe quantos registros virão, antes que de fato venham - depois disso talvez haja a necessidade de aplicar outros filtros como deve ser o caso de subselects e afins...

Comment: A menos que você esteja falando de uma quantidade absurdamente grande re registros e que leva um tempo considerável para ser recuperado (mais que 2 minutos, por exemplo), quase que isso não vale a pena. Monitorar esse tipo de processamento para dar um tempo estimado de término em geral vai levar mais tempo do que o processamento e retorno da consulta em si.

Comment: Cara, vc quer prever o tempo? Faz uma média, porque prever acredito que não seja possivel, mas através de uma média, por exemplo, calcula o tempo de execução de 100 querys diferentes, vc acha o tempo de cada valor de cada query e faz uma media para cada registro, assim vc consegue prever, aproximadamente, uma busca para 1000 resultados, por exemplo.

Comment: As queries que estou querendo buscar essa estimativa realmente levam bastante tempo, são tabelas com JOIN's e que algumas possuem alguns milhões de registros. Acredito que nesse caso talvez a melhor opção seja essa mesmo Wees verificar com uma pequena amostra e eu fazer uma estimativa a parte para verificar essa questão

Comment: Não sei até que ponto isso influenciaria mas, um comando COUNT costuma ser muito mais rápido para executar. Nesse caso se tivesse uma maneira de o BD executar esse contador total e a medida que vai executando a query principal ir mostrando o quanto falta, por exemplo: 1/100, 2/100.... 100/100 já daria para estimar também

Comment: Não é possível prever o tempo de execução, mesmo baseado em estatísticas anteriores, média, ou coisa do tipo.. imagine que algum faça um *lock* na tabela ou tente criar um índice, executar um backup, qualquer coisa em tempo de execução irá furar a previsão, dai vai ser uma coisa sem credibilidade, igual aquele "tempo estimado" quando copia arquivos no *Windows*, quem nunca dá certo :(